# PIVOT Table Date & Year wise data display sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, pivot

this is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT CurDate, YEAR(CurDate) AS orderyear, Warranty_Info
      FROM eod_main where year(CurDate)>=2009 and year(CurDate)<=2011) AS D
  PIVOT(SUM(Warranty_Info) FOR orderyear IN([2009],[2010],[2011])) AS P
```

the above query return data but CurDate return date it is is return multiple date for same month.

i want that `SUM(Warranty_Info)` should return only once for every month and year

output should look like

```
Month     2009     2010    2011    2012   2013
-----     ----     ----    ----    ----   -----
1          10       0       11      32      98
2          20       10      21      11      44
3          0        224     33      77      31
```

some kind of problem is there in my query and that is why it is returning multiple data for same month like

[image]

please help me to have the right query. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `CurDate` as the full date with year, month and day, I would suggest using the [`Month()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) function to return the numeric value of each month.  This will allow you to group by month instead of the full date:

```
SELECT dateMonth, [2009],[2010],[2011]
FROM 
(
  SELECT month(CurDate) dateMonth, 
    YEAR(CurDate) AS orderyear, Warranty_Info
  FROM eod_main 
  where year(CurDate)>=2009 
    and year(CurDate)<=2011
) AS D
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Warranty_Info) 
  FOR orderyear IN([2009],[2010],[2011])
) AS P;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef312/2)